# How to manage the concurrency using hibernate Transaction API

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, concurrency, distributed-transactions

I have the application which is running in the distributed environment. 
I want to have a scenario like if two simultaneous requests are coming to me to update the table. if the first request successfully updates the table the next request should not get executed/ discard with some message. so the user has to again load updated data and do update operation again. 
**solution**
I have found one common **solution** was version control by adding one key in the table as version and compare it every time while updating the table.

I am looking for some other solution as Hibernate is robust framework there will be other ways to achieve this solution.

By reading an article of JBoss there is something called transaction API through which also we can achieve but not getting clarity on how to achieve the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Hibernate can use both optimistic and pessimistic locking as explained in the [official documentation, Chapter 5. Locking](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/devguide/en-US/html/ch05.html).

If your database entities are not contended than optimisitc locking with `@Version` column seems as the right approach. If you require pessimistic locking check the `LockMode` class. Another option would be to use `SELECT FOR UPDATE` statement if it's available in your database. However all pessimistic locking approaches are usually more expensive than simple optimistic locking solution due to additional database operations that happen under the hood.

Comment: I have gone through the versioning approach if you can help me with any other approach

Comment: Check the `Session.lock()` method documentation and see what your RDBMS is providing e.g. PostgreSQL has entire chapter on locking: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/explicit-locking.html. Distributed transactions on multiple resources are an entirely different concept see XA or 2PC-best-effort approach.

Comment: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#transactions 
Please check this link we can achieve by TransactionCoordinatorBuilder, but not getting source how to configure this.

Comment: Locking is not transaction coordination. You can have either resource local (1PC) or distributed transaction (2PC, usually XA over JTA). Your docs looks like something that you normally don't touch in your application unless you are writing your own JTA implementation. Please note that I never used `TransactionCoordinatorBuilder` so I might be wrong here.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and looked into mine problem. Please share if you have any source through which I can achieve this then this will be a great help for me.

Comment: I'd start with overview: https://www.javaworld.com/article/2077963/open-source-tools/distributed-transactions-in-spring--with-and-without-xa.html. Than I'd dig into XA and understand under which conditions XA can fail e.g. permanent resource failure. Than see which resources don't support XA e.g. AMQP queues like RabbitMQ and why (usually performance). Ideally you want to also understand what are transaction savepoints in the DB: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/sql-savepoint.html.